# Music coming out of a socket

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

This incident happened a couple of years ago, back when I was in school. A classmate and I were sitting in a room when we started hearing music coming out of an electric socket. It took us a while to realize but there was no way it could have been from a different source. We confirmed it several times, since it made no sense to us. It was the last room on that side of the building and it definitely was not coming from the room above or below.

So my question is how is that possible? Sorry if it's super obvious or something. I don't do a lot of physics stuff.

Comment: The presence of a socket means there is a hole in the wall. This makes it easier for sound to come through there, and not elsewhere.

Comment: I doubt that anyone will be able to definitively answer this question given this information. The sound was probably being transmitted through some feature of the walls - like a conduit carrying the wires - but the number of possibilities is wide open. What we probably can rule out was that the sound was being carried electrically.

Comment: Any idea of the construction, for example (hollow) concrete or "cinder" blocks?

Comment: @KeithMcClary no idea, all I know it's not an old building, but no idea when it was built or how